# Como puedo solucionar error de trailing data en laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hace 2 dias que estoy trabajando con una parte de un proyecto, y me indica un error de trailing data cuando accedo al index del modulo, el proyecto esta con laravel 5.3,
A pesar de intentar varias soluciones, incluyendo modificar la codificación de JSON y convertir los datos a un array PHP antes de pasarlos a la vista, el error persiste.

¿Hay algo más que debería intentar o alguna sugerencia adicional para solucionar este error de "trailing data" en Laravel 5.3?

¡Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan ofrecer para resolver este problema! el codigo que tengo en la vista es el siguiente:

```php
    @section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Ventas
            <small>Listado</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ventas</a></li>
            <li class="active">Lista</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        @include('partials._flashes')
        <div class="box">

            <div class="box-header">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <a href="{{ route('venta.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> &nbsp; Agregar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" title="Convertir tabla en archivo excel."
                            id="export">
                            <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span> &nbsp; Exportar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'sale_export', 'method' => 'POST', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'form_export']) !!}
                <input name="json" id="json" type="hidden" value='{!! $export_list !!}'>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

                <div class="box-tools">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:150px;">
                        {!! Form::model(Request::only(['name']), ['route' => 'venta.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'search']) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('num_venta', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm pull-right', 'placeholder' => 'Numero de Venta', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body  no-padding">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @if ($ventas)
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tbody>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width:10px">#</th>
                                            <th>Número de Serie</th>
                                            <th>Grupo</th>
                                            <th>Tipo de Venta</th>
                                            <th>Monto</th>
                                            <th>Vendedor</th>
                                            <th>Número de Venta</th>
                                            <th style="width:150">Creado</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($ventas as $venta)
                                        <tr data-id="{{ $venta->id }}">
                                            <td>{{ $venta->id }}.</td>
                                            <td>{{ $venta->num_serie }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $venta->group->description }}</td>
                                            @if ($venta->tipo_venta == 'co')
                                                <td>Contado</td>
                                            @else
                                                <td>Credito</td>
                                            @endif
                                            <td>{{ number_format($venta->amount, 0) }}</td>
                                            @if ($venta->vendedor != null)
                                                <td>{{ $venta->vendedor }}</td>
                                            @else
                                                <td> </td>
                                            @endif
                                            @if ($venta->num_venta != null)
                                                <td>{{ $venta->num_venta }}</td>
                                            @else
                                                <td> </td>
                                            @endif
                                            <td>{{ date('d/m/y H:i', strtotime($venta->created_at)) }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="dataTables_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">{{ $ventas->total() }} registros en
                            total
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers">
                            {!! $ventas->appends(Request::only(['id']))->render() !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['venta.destroy', ':ROW_ID'], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'form-delete']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

**Mi controlador relacionado tiene lo siguiente**

```php
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->user->hasAccess('ventas')) {
            \Log::error(
                'Unauthorized access attempt',
                ['user' => $this->user->username, 'route' => \Request::route()->getActionName()]
            );
            Session::flash('error_message', 'No tiene los permisos para realizar esta operacion');
            return redirect('/');
        }

        $num_venta = null;

        if (isset($request['num_venta'])) {
            $num_venta = $request->get('num_venta');
        }

        $ventas = Venta::filterAndPaginate($num_venta);

        $export_list = $this->get_sale_list($num_venta);

        return view('ventas.index', compact('ventas', 'num_venta', 'export_list'));
    }

private function get_sale_list($num_venta)
    {

        $export_list = [];

        try {
            $export_list = \DB::table('venta as v')
                ->select(
                    'v.id',
                    'h.serialnumber',
                    'bg.description',
                    \DB::raw("case when v.tipo_venta = 'co' then 'Contado' else 'Crédito' end as tipo_venta"),
                    'v.amount',
                    'v.vendedor',
                    \DB::raw("case when v.num_venta is not null then v.num_venta else 'Sin número de venta' end as num_venta"),
                    \DB::raw("to_char(v.created_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as created_at")
                )
                ->join('business_groups as bg', 'bg.id', '=', 'v.group_id')
                ->join('venta_housing as vh', 'v.id', '=', 'vh.venta_id')
                ->join('housing as h', 'h.id', '=', 'vh.housing_id');

            if (trim($num_venta) != '') {
                $export_list->where('v.num_venta', $num_venta);
            }

            $export_list = $export_list
                ->orderBy('v.id', 'desc')
                ->get();

            $export_list = json_encode($export_list, true);

            //\Log::debug("VENTA: ", [$export_list]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error("Error en listado: {$e->getMessage()}");
        }

        return $export_list;
    }
```

> Cualquier ayuda al respecto me vendria bien, ya no se me ocurren opciones para probar :c*

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado chicos, si a alguien le llega a pasar un error similar la solucion fue agregar un mutador de fecha al modelo para que pase un formato receptible a la vista a traves del controlador luego, el mutador que agregué fue el siguiente:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    try {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $value)->format('d/m/y H:i');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null; 
    }
}
```